# Rest-Assured: How to clean up test data?

Tags: java, junit, integration-testing, rest-assured

I'm trying to start writing new integration tests for my rest apis. One the basic requirement is to be able to create a user but user cannot delete itself. Only system's superUser is allowed to delete this user. What is the best way of doing test data cleanup?

I can do superUser login using hardcoded email and password and then do the cleanup, but I really don't like the credentials to be hardcoded in the test code...

Answer (score 0):

If you are running your tests with TestNG/JUnit, in the @After part I would make the cleanup with the harded super user.